# UICollectionView With iOS 7? margin space

Tags: iphone, ios, uicollectionview

I just working to update my app to iOS 7 with xCode 5 GM

but the UICollectionView looks like crap on iOS 7 Only

but with iOS 6 it's works like candy :)

I don't know what's going on? any one test UICollectionView on xCode 5

the problem is there no space between cells, they all on one cell - one above one

even, i created new project to test UICollectionView with iOS 7, but same problem

and I tried UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout Methods to set values,, but same problem no space !!!!

needs little help here

thanks in advance...

Comment: Do you have AutoLayout turned on. In my experience it can do some funky things if not set up correctly.

Comment: The problem only on iOS 7 - but on iOS 6 it's works fine,,,,, i don't know whats going on????

Answer (score 4):

Don't update `cell.frame.orgin`. you can change cell.frame.size but not `cell.frame.orgin` in

- `(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {}`

Comment: +100: I had the same issue and just updating my code  that resizes the cells with your advice ((keeping X and Y coordinates)  fixed the issue!